# Powershell - move and rename

Tags: powershell

I guys,
I am new to powershell and I have a problem.
I want to change from 14283963_5206074553_17052013-9102945.pdf
to 5206074553.pdf
can anyone help me?

Thank you

Comment: Hi Ricardo, what have you done already? If you don't post some of your code, people won't reply and will downvote your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't just want to rename a file with this particular name, but a name of the form `aaaaa_bbbbb_ccccc-ddddd.pdf` to `bbbbb.pdf` you could do something like this:

```
$oldname = '14283963_5206074553_17052013-9102945.pdf'
$newname = $oldname -replace '.*?_(.*?)_.*?(\..*)','$1$2'
Rename-Item $oldname $newname
```

This code needs to be run from the directory containing the file `$oldname`.

Comment: Hi guys,thanks for your help.
Ansgar you are right

I end up with this script

$Source = "C:\test"
$Dest = "C:\test1"

get-childitem $Source | Foreach-Object {
  Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination "$Dest\$($_.name -replace '.*?_(.*?)_.*?(\..*)','$1$2')" -WhatIf
}

and the message showed is:
What if: Performing operation "Move File" on Target "Item: C:\test\14283945_5206074470_17052013-9102943.pdf Destination:
 C:\test1\5206074470.pdf".
 
but the files aren´t changed

Comment: To actually perform the operation you need to remove the `-WhatIf` switch.

Comment: Thank you. It worked.
I'm new in powershell and regex.
Can you indicate the best way to learn about it?

Thank you again

Comment: As with everything, practice makes perfect. For a tutorial try [this](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/ebookv2/default.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

try this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176940.aspx

go to the folder where the file is you want to rename and than type this:

```
Rename-Item 14283963_5206074553_17052013-9102945.pdf 5206074553.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

[In Linux you use the `mv` command.](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-rename-files-in-linux/) `mv` is short for move. It's also a build-in alias for PowerShell.

```
mv  source target
mv [Options]  source target
```

Here's how you'd do it in PowerShell:

```
mv 'C:\14283963_5206074553_17052013-9102945.pdf' 'C:\5206074553.pdf'
```

There you go. You just learned how to rename files in PowerShell and Linux.